# Route [auth.register] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-jetstream

So my problem is that I am getting this error and I have no idea what it means....

```
Symfony \ Component \ Routing \ Exception \ RouteNotFoundException
Route [auth.register] not defined.

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php&line=467

    public function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)

    {

        if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name))) {

            return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);

        }



        throw new RouteNotFoundException("Route [{$name}] not defined."); //  <= Line 467

    }
```

I am thinking it's probably because my naming is wrong in web.php...

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProgramController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/index', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', config('jetstream.auth_session'), 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('program', \App\Http\Controllers\ProgramController::class);
    
    Route::resource('manager', \App\Http\Controllers\ManagerController::class);
});
```

I think maybe it's because since I named it middleware and it's pointing to auth maybe that's the reason I got that error. But I wanted to at least show all the user. I would be very grateful if anyone can help.

Comment: it means you have no route defined named 'auth.register'

Comment: run ```php artisan route:list``` to see whether ```auth.register``` is exist or not

Comment: So what should I do if it's not? Because my views does have auth/register.blade.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I got forgot I wrote the code wrong and one of the route is pointing at auth.register when it supposed to lead to manager.create in the manager/index.blade.php

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Management') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="block mb-8">
                <a href="{{ route('auth.register') }}" class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Add User</a>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <div class="-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
                    <div class="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        <div class="shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg">
                            <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 w-full">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" width="50" class="px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                        ID
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                        Name
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                        Email
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                        Email Verified At
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                        Roles
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="200" class="px-6 py-3 bg-gray-50">

                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                                @foreach ($manager as $user)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-900">
                                            {{ $user->id }}
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-900">
                                            {{ $user->name }}
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-900">
                                            {{ $user->email }}
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-900">
                                            {{ $user->email_verified_at }}
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-900">
                                            @foreach ($user->roles as $role)
                                                <span class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-green-100 text-green-800">
                                                    {{ $role->title }}
                                                </span>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium">
                                            <a href="{{ route('manager.show', $user->id) }}" class="text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-900 mb-2 mr-2">View</a>
                                            <a href="{{ route('manager.edit', $user->id) }}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900 mb-2 mr-2">Edit</a>
                                            <form class="inline-block" action="{{ route('manager.destroy', $user->id) }}" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                                <input type="submit" class="text-red-600 hover:text-red-900 mb-2 mr-2" value="Delete">
                                            </form>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</x-app-layout>
```

So in the end I was being weird. So if you guys have any problem don't panic like me just read the code again you might have missed something.